# JMeter - compare assersion between two variables

Tags: jmeter

I have two variables (create_date) took from SQL queries, and I want to validate the results.
Using Regular Expression I fetch both created date and I want to make sure that the dates is not equal.
I have created the following BeanShell assersion to compare both variables:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tUleL.png)

however, I'm getting the following error:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oGbHG.png)

Answer (score 0):

You're mixing 2 approaches:

1. Referencing variables like `${CreateDateBefore}` in scripts (which you should not be using at all)
2. And using `vars` shorthand for [JMeterVariables](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterVariables.html) class instance

Apart from this you're using [double](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html) to store some form of a timestamp

So you need to update your code like:

```
String var1 = vars.get("CreateDateBefore");
String var2 = vars.get("CreateDateAfter");
```

Also be aware that [since JMeter 3.1 you should be using JSR223 Test Elements and Groovy language](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting) for scripting so consider migrating to [JSR223 Assertion](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/scripting-jmeter-assertions-in-groovy-a-tutorial)

And last but not the least, you can compare 2 JMeter Variables using "normal" [Response Assertion](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Response_Assertion) configured like:

[image]